# JavaScript build nested array from string values

Tags: javascript, arrays

From my data source I am getting values like;

```
USA        |Arizona
USA        |Florida
UK         |England |Northamptonshire
UK         |England |Derbyshire
UK         |Wales   |Powys
Switzerland|Lucern
```

These are flat text values that repeat in a column.

I need to build them dynamically into nested array

```
source: [
    {title: "USA",  children: [
      {title: "Arizona"},
      {title: "Florida"}
    ]}
  ],
```

As per https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData

Unfortunately my brain has stopped working today I am can't see a elegant way.

Any pointers would be most gratefully appreciated.

So I solved this eventually using a post from Oskar

```js
function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
    var out = []
    for(var i in arr) {
        if(arr[i].parent == parent) {
            var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)

            if(children.length) {
                arr[i].children = children
            }
            out.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

http://oskarhane.com/create-a-nested-array-recursively-in-javascript/

This builds the nested array.

To ensure inferred values were present (e.g. USA which is in the hierarchy but is not a unique value).

```js
  var CountryArray = CountryText.split("|");
 
  // Variables to hold details of each section of the Country path being iterated
  var CountryId = '';
  var CountryParentPrefix = '';
  var CountryParent = '';

  // Iterate each section of the delimeted Country path and ensure that it is in the array
  for(var i in CountryArray) 
  {

   var CountryId = CountryParentPrefix+CountryArray[i];
 
   // Find the Country id in the array / add if necessary
   var result = FlatSource.filter(function (Country) { return Country.id == CountryId });
   if (result.length == 0) {
     // If the Country is not there then we should add it
     var arrCountry = {title:CountryArray[i], parent:CountryParent, id:CountryId};
     FlatSource.push(arrCountry);
   }
   

   // For the next path of the heirarchy
   CountryParent = CountryId;
   CountryParentPrefix = CountryId+'|';
  }
```

I did not use Sven's suggestion but I suspect that it is equally valid.

Comment: Can you see a not-so-elegant way? Please post what you tried.

Comment: Does your data source an array of string ? like ["USA|Arizona","USA|Florida"]

Comment: How deep can the "nesting" be? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page: without complete information, it's difficult to help. Also, it's generally good to make an effort, and show that you've made that effort, to help people understand you're not just looking for a handout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn it to JSON:

```
var str = '"USA|Arizona","USA|Florida","UK|LonelyIsland","UK|England|Northamptonshire","UK|England|Derbyshire","UK|Wales|Powys","UK|England|London|Soho","Switzerland|Lucern';

var jsonStr = "[[" + str.replace(/,/g,'],[') + "\"]]";
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(/\|/g,'","');
var nested = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

Then play with parents and children.

```
function findObject(array, key, value) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][key] === value) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function obj(arr){
    this.title = arr.shift();
}

obj.prototype.addChild = function(arr){
    var tmp = new obj(arr);
    if(typeof this.children === 'undefined'){
        this.children = new Array();
        result = this.children[this.children.push(tmp)-1];
    }else{
        result = findObject(this.children, 'title', tmp.title);
        if(!result)
            result = this.children[this.children.push(tmp)-1];
    }
    return result;
}

obj.prototype.addChildren = function(arr){
    var obje = this;
    while(arr.length>0)
        obje = obje.addChild(arr);
}


var finArr = [];
for(i=0; i<nested.length; i++){
    var recc = new obj(nested[i]);
    if(oldObj = findObject(finArr, 'title', recc.title)){
        oldObj.addChildren(nested[i]);
    }else{
        if(nested[i].length>0)
                recc.addChildren(nested[i]);
        finArr.push(recc);        
    }
}

console.log('------------------------------------------')
console.log(JSON.stringify(finArr));
console.log('--------------------The End---------------')
```

Comment: Sven, many thanks.  I found a different way in the end but this is v.helpful and I have marked as such.